# how to run selenium html suite parallely on same pc in 3 different browsers?

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, selenium, dos

I am running CHROME, FF, IE parallely by changing port number the command is:

```
java -jar D:\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -htmlSuite "*googlechrome C:\chrome.exe" http://localhost/test/ D:\selenium\TS6.html C:\RES\Result_TS6.html -port 4448

and -port 4452 for FF
and -port 4456 for IE
```

CHROME runs perfectly fine and close after completion BUT

when FF completes its automation **it is closing IE rather than FF**
and FF remains running forever....
Can anybody suggest why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run selenium-server-standalone multiple times with different parameters. However seeing as you are experiencing unexpected behavior it can be concluded that such usage is not supported, as there is also no documentation to be found. To find the root cause of your problem more debugging needs to be done.

The selenium-standalone-server comes bundled with the Grid server. The Grid server has been designed (for exactly what you want) to execute and manage multiple tests. This allows you to execute multiple tests parallel, manage your browser configurations and keep track of the test results.

On http://docs.seleniumhq.org there is a guide on how to setup the Grid server.

It is unknown, and highly unlikely, that it is possible to run a Selenium IDE HTML Suite `-htmlSuite` directly with the Grid server. There is no documentation to be found on this. However, it is possible to export an existing Selenium IDE HTML Suite to WebDriver compatible code.

Of course you can always opted for running the tests in multiple virtual machines, this route also solves the problem from not being able to run multiple instances.

Comment: you mean to say hub and node concept?

Comment: and moreover i found that it is not a problem of 3 browsers, if i run only firefox and internet explorer it happens the same.

Comment: Correct, use the Grid server (hub/node concept) for executing tests simultaneous and parallel.

Comment: but node and hub concept is explained only for executing java test cases using command line but how to execute html suites?

Comment: Not possible, '-htmlSuite' is part of Selenium 1 and cannot be used with Selenium Grid that is part of Selenium 2.